# Duplicate information on tag search page when user's id is used

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tag-search

I clicked on a tag on my activity tab of my profile page:

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:3840840+[twitter-bootstrap]

And I get the following:

[image]

On this screenshot we can see the tag description (red arrow) and the search bar (blue arrow) twice.

You can get the same result using the search bar using the following expression: `user:XXXXXXX [tagname]` or `user:me [tagname]`.

I don't know the technical background, but in my opinion this duplicate information is not needed.

Comment: I think it should probably be tagged as bug

Comment: Repro'ed. Doesn't seem to occur on meta.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - Yes, on meta only the search bar is shown twice.

Comment: I'd separate _remove the double tag info_, which is fixing a bug, and _remove the double search bar_, which occurs on way more pages and likely isn't a bug. Having both these in one request will likely cause the last one to be ignored

Comment: You may reproduce it while searching `user:me [tagname]` too.

Comment: Thank god it didn't appear the 3rd time, otherwise the button would have been labeled: **Watch The Tag NOW** the 3rd time around

Comment: Along with this came hiding the link to sort the results by "votes" under "more"... More whitespace and more clicks required...

Comment: A similar case: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372258/3995261 , without  the `user` bit, just any search request aside tag

Comment: also reported on MSE now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318259/duplicated-tag-description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the delay on this; this should be fixed next build - thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is reproducible for me with *any* SO search including a tag and something else:

[image]

But I can't reproduce it on SO meta or elsewhere:

[image]