# Tag description duplicated in search interface

Tags: bug

If you visit a search page like https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+empty+element , you'll probably see what I see:

[image]

The tag description is shown twice. This doesn't happen if the query contains only a tag: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]

Comment: Thanks @Xufox, I haven't found it with quick search

Comment: @DavyM yes, sure, I understand why duplicates usually shouldn't be deleted